# Multithreaded file copy for Linux needed

Tags: multithreading, file, copy

I have a "large" amount of data that needs to be copied every day. (6TB)

It is 15 disks presented from a SAN over Fibre Channel and being copied to a local array consisting of 22 spindles.

```
sources are 
/mnt/disk1
/mnt/disk2
/mnt/disk3

destination is
/mnt/Data/SystemBackup/
```

Due to the nature of our SAN, single threaded file copy is not very fast; but it is very capable of 600+mb/sec if we ask it in the right way. :) I need a way to spawn multiple threads in a file copy. There are MANY ways to do this in windows... but I can't find any native methods available to Linux.

Could something like Python or Perl be of assistance? Is there something I'm missing? What are your thoughts?

Edit: 
(Please note, I am using a modified version of gnutils cp.) Read here for more info: http://www.usenix.org/event/lisa10/tech/slides/kolano.pdf

Edit2: The code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare the foo
OPTIONS="-r --double-buffer --threads=8"
dstdir="/mnt/Data/PrUv2Backup/"
mcp=/root/mcp

# Cleanup old timestamp file
rm -rf PrUv2CopyTimes.log

# Declare array of source locations
srcdirs=(
PrUv2-home
PrUv2-trax
PrUv2-trax2
PrUv2-trax3
PrUv2-traxnl
PrUv2-traxnl2
PrUv2-traxnl3
PrUv2-traxnl4
PrUv2-traxnv
PrUv2-traxnv2
PrUv2-ulog
PrUv2-zmops
PrUv2-zmops2
PrUv2-zmops3
PrUv2-zmops4
)


for srcdir in "${srcdirs[@]}"

do
        echo `date +"%r"` $srcdir start  >> PrUv2CopyTimes.log
        $mcp $OPTIONS /mnt/$srcdir/ $dstdir
        echo `date +"%r"` $srcdir finish >> PrUv2CopyTimes.log
done

# email results
cat PrUv2CopyTimes.log | mailx -r LouPrBoxen001 -s "Backup Complete" me@us.com
```

Comment: When you say "if we ask it in the right way", what exactly is "the right way"? I think the threading architecture critically depends on that.

Comment: This may sound silly, but in your copying script, couldn't you perform the copy operations in _parallel_? That ensures that your copy operations will effectively _max out_ your bandwidth. Of course you'll have to weigh the _number_ of operations you do in parallel vs performance et al but you get the idea.

Comment: "The right way" is kind of an unknown to me. I know that it handles random IO in a wicked fast sort of way. It likes having lots of requests and lots to do... if you ask to copy a single large file, it just can't give you the IO.

Comment: @MarvinPinto - I could, but I don't know how. I'll edit and post up my original copy script.

Comment: Why don't you simply run several `rsync` in parallel, each copying a different source directory?

Comment: 1. As I stated I don't know how to run things in parallel like that... I could break the script out and each one does 3 or 4 sets of directories... 2. rsync has issues with going deep enough into directory trees. It won't copy all of our files.

Answer (score 0):

just got [**ultracopier**](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/), you may give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if this will work for the original question as the SAN isn't exactly a host, just a networked storage array.  Maybe you could find a host close by the SAN to act as an additional host.

If you are needing to copy a large number of small files from one host to another over a network, you will find that it takes a very long time.  Each file one after the other is copied and the bandwidth is barely a blip.  There is a technique to on the fly compress the files and directories and pipe them through a raw network port where a receiving host is listening and then decompress on the destination.  This causes the copy process to create a huge single file redirected to the network port and that will saturate the network quite nicely.  The result is it will speed it up and you don't need extra elbow room on the source host as the compression never hits the disk but is redirected via the pipe to the raw network port.  This works very well and is a great way to boot a laptop with a USB Linux system and extract the data to a remote host. Or copy from a remote server.

Receiver:

nc -l 3245 | bunzip2 -vvv | tar -x

Sender:

tar -c folder/ | bzip2 -vv9 | nc 10.1.1.5 3245

It would also be possible to make a ssh tunnel and use netcat over that encrypted tunnel.

Depending on the size of the individual files this can save as much as 40% or more in copy time.  If you have large files this won't matter as much as each file will have time to saturate the network bandwidth on it's own.  This is most useful with a lot of smallish files.